# Combining numerical time duration entries in an array that overlap

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have an `[starttime in seconds, duration in seconds]` array, like this

```
[0.2, 0.4]
[0.3, 0.5]
[0.6, 0.5]
[10.6, 0.5]
```

I want to combine overlapping times, ie the aforementioned array should convert into

```
[0.2, 0.9]
[10.6, 0.5]
```

What is the elegant solution?

Comment: i'd suggest [providing MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Comment: 0.6+0.5 = 1.1 --> 1.1 - 0.2 = 0.9

Comment: @cryptonome there is no code to reproduce the problem

Comment: fabien, you're the one who asked for a help. think about that & if the requests are unreasonable if the roles are reversed.

Comment: @cryptonome You know just like me that the motivation for people to write answers is two-fold. First, they like the challenge and feel good having solved a problem and second, they want many people to see their reply to get good job offers. None of the two is being influenced by how much I did. And lastly, most of the time exactly those, who demand examples, don't write solutions once they are, or are not given. Just the way it happened here, where is your solution cryptonome and jpp?

Comment: your response is completely irrelevant to the facts that 1. you were the one asking for help, 2. you were the one who refused to provide more details & proof of efforts as the site outlined, 3. call someone whose comment you disagree with as 'insecure' for nonsense reasons; 4. you expected people to obey your wish just because you think you know what other people's motivations are or what "most of the time..." happens, and 5. _you were the one asking for help_.

Comment: exactly the proof of no.4, you think you know more than other people "As soon as you are interested in facing reality...", yet the stark reality is you were the one who asked for help from strangers in a site that you have very little knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have lists with all the input data and they are sorted by starttime

```
   a=[[0.2,0.4],[0.3,0.5],[0.6,0.5],[10.6,0.5]] # each element is list of form [start,duration]
   output =[] # output would be stored here
   for x in a: # iterate through input
    if output: # if we have previous output to compare
        st = x[0] # current start time
        dur = x[1] # current durtion time
        prev_st = output[-1][0] # previous computed output start time
        prev_dur = output[-1][1] # previous computed output duration
        if prev_st<=st<= (prev_st+prev_dur): # check if current info can be part of previous output
            updated_list=[] Update the latest output with new info
            updated_list.append(prev_st) #start would remain the same as it is sorted
            updated_list.append(max(prev_dur,st+dur-prev_st)) # duration can be different as per current info
            output[-1] = updated_list
        else:
            output.append(x)
    else:
        output.append(x) # append first list as it is
```